# Adding arguments for batch script in command line

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

I'm trying to call arguments for running a script with the rsync command. I've tried various forms and this is the most "simple", however I continue to get an error.

#### (bash.sh)

```
#! /bin/bash
root_dir = $1
target_dir = $2
rsync -avh -P --stats $root_dir $target_dir
echo "Files Transferred!"
```

#### ErrorMessage

```
test.sh: line 2: root_dir: command not found
test.sh: line 3: target_dir: command not found
```

#### Command Line

```
sh bash.sh ./path_root_dir ./path_target_dir
```

Comment: There must be no spaces in `variable=value`.

Comment: adding to the comment by @meuh, it is recommended that you keep your values quoted especially when they are strings.

Comment: paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation.

Comment: @Jetchisel this is a pretty neat place to check my shell script, very useful indeed. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Using a variable with a space, without using speech marks or a quote on each side can cause an error to occur, especially when the variable is used and there was a space in the value.

Another way you could try is to use an array, the options variable is where the array is, and then it is called in the rsync command below,

```
directory="/etc"
backupDirectory="/backup"
incrementalBackup="/incremental"
options=(-a -e 'ssh -p 10022' -b --backup-dir="$incrementalBackup" --delete)
# rsync
rsync "${options[@]}" user@server:"$directory" "$backupDirectory"
```

Comment: This doesn't explain what the problem was and how to solve it.